# Home.jsx: GET http://localhost:<PORT#>/books 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, express, http

I am using express.js with mongoose, all requests are working fine through postman, but when I have created a frontend folder next to the backend one, I can't seem to get to the url API

```
// React imports
import { useEffect } from "react";

//Axios
import axios from "axios";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5173/books`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div>Home</div>;
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please add more useful details, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you're hitting an endpoint which is not available in the backend it seems. Check once again that which endpoint you're trying to access, also provide the exact exception you're facing and try following the conventions to ask a question.